# Good introductory material for bootstrap?

Tags: references, bootstrap

I am considering the use of bootstrap method to estimate standard errors or confidence intervals for the method I am developing.

Two candidate books are

Efron and Tibshirani (1993)
[http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Bootstrap-Monographs-Statistics-Probability/dp/0412042312/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1452238861&sr=8-1&keywords=bootstrap+efron](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412042312)

and

Davison and Hinkley (1997)
[http://www.amazon.com/Bootstrap-Application-Statistical-Probabilistic-Mathematics/dp/0521574714/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1452238861&sr=8-2&keywords=bootstrap+efron](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521574714)

Which one is better for the novice to implement the method?

Comment: I saw that such question is more appropriate for 'community wiki', but I couldn't find how to post there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like both, and both are fairly accessible. In fact, I benefited from reading both, as their subtly different ways of explaining things complemented each other well. However, reading both as a first introduction to the bootstrap is probably overkill.

In short, you can't go wrong with either one.